# How to access Emotiv Epoc X raw EEG data

Tags: python, brain-computer-interface

I've recently purchased an Emotiv Epoc X because I wanted to start diving into BCI. To my surprise I've found out that most of the features are not available for free but paying a very expensive monthly subscription. My goal would be obtaining raw EEG data (mainly for research purposes) and maybe trying to interface the Epoc with some game.

I've seen that a lot of people use an old python program to obtain the raw data. Is it still viable for my device (I can't make it work https://github.com/faturita/python-nerv/commit/840c54b46acd39c4b6cda310cd217edf49debe98)? Also, regarding the game-control thing, is it doable via non paid subscription "mental commands" or every single guy that does it on YouTube is paying the subscription?